# Why don't the EC2 cloud images use the EC2 repository mirrors for the Security repository?

Tags: apt, updates, amazon-ec2

I started up a new server and had it do an `apt-get update` and noticed that it was taking a very long time.  I noticed that `sources.list` has trusty-security enabled with a URL of `security.ubuntu.com`.  My server happened to grab a very slow mirror.

My question is, why isn't this defaulted to `us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com` (or whatever other applicable region) like the main trusty repos are?

Comment: Seems like a question for EC2 customer support.

Comment: Oh, I was unaware that AWS maintained the Ubuntu cloud images.

Comment: They don't, they're produced by Canonical if I remember right, and provided to Amazon as the images for installation.  The use of `security.ubuntu.com` is for a different reason, as detailed in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The security updates are set to pull from `security.ubuntu.com` so that security updates are immediately available when published and released, rather than the systems pulling in updates having to rely on a potentially out of date mirror's update cycles to execute before you get the security fixes.

For the other top level country mirrors, they're either specific locations for specific repositories (such as Partner), or they're country regional mirrors, or in the case of AWS EC2 images, the EC2 repositories in that region which run on AWS infrastructure but are maintained by Canonical.

Other third-party mirror stats can be seen for some of the publicly listed ones [here on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors).

Comment: That makes sense.  Is there a way to tell how behind a mirror is?  Or do you know typically how far behind the S3 mirrors are?

Comment: @tubaguy50035 there's no way to tell exactly how far behind a mirror is, no.  Usually, the country regional mirrors and the ec2 mirrors are up to date with maybe an hour's difference, but it's still more safe to pull from `security.ubuntu.com` for the security updates as they're published there as the primary location of them.  You can't guarantee a mirror is updated, or is even pulling in and mirroring the security repos.  (This answer should answer your initial question, though)

Comment: It does, I just can't select it as the answer for another couple minutes...

Comment: For official mirrors not run by Canonical, https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors has some information on how up-to-date they are.